# FileReader is not being fired on a web worker

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have the below function that convert pdfs to images, the function is within a web worker.

For some reason the `fileReader.onload` is not being fired, the `filePdf` is correct and is on the right format. Any idea?

```
const processFile = async (filePdf, post) => {
  let PDFJS
  if (!PDFJS) {
    PDFJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js')
  }
  if (!filePdf) return
  const fileReader = new FileReader()
  console.log(filePdf)
  let pages
  try {
    fileReader.onload = async () => {
      const pdf = await PDFJS.getDocument(fileReader.result).promise
      pages = await pdfToImageMap(pdf)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log({e})
  }
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(filePdf)
  return post({type: 'done'})
}
```

`filePdf`:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you put `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(filePdf)` inside of the `try` block?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier When I do so the `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(filePdf)` is being fired.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier No, it doesn't, I'm not sure I understood what you meant. Would you be able to give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your logic.

At the moment you are trying to wait for the onload, which will work. So the `try` block succeeds. Then you return your `post` function. So you've run the file reader, but didn't wait for it load and returned with the `post` function.

Instead wait for the `fileReader` to load by awaiting a promise wrapped around the load function. And inside the `Promise` call `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(filePdf)` to make sure that the `onload` function is called. In the `onload` function use your `try / catch` block to use your `PDFJS` framework.

Also, don't waste any values stored in variables. If the `pages` value is something you need, then use it and return it somehow. Otherwise don't store the value and discard it.

Try the snippet below and see if it works.

```
const processFile = async (filePdf, post) => {
  const PDFJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js')
  if (!filePdf) return
  console.log(filePdf)
  const fileReader = new FileReader()
  const pages = await new Promise(resolve => {
    fileReader.onload = async () => {
      try {
        const pdf = await PDFJS.getDocument(fileReader.result).promise
        const pages = await pdfToImageMap(pdf)
        resolve(pages)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log({e})
      }
    }
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(filePdf)
  })
  return post({type: 'done', pages})
}
```